# Disable a manual keyboard input JavaScript/Oracle JET

Tags: javascript, html, oracle-jet

I'm developing an application with Oracle JET framework and I'm using a combobox input as shown in the Oracle JET Cookbook.

How can I disable a manual keyboard input?

I tried to add this in my input but none of this command worked:

```
onkeypress="return false;"
onkeydown="return false"



<input id="combobox" list="browsers" 
       data-bind="ojComponent: {component: 'ojCombobox', 
                                multiple: true, value: val,
                                rootAttributes: {style:'max-width:20em'}}"/>
<datalist id="browsers">
    <option value="Internet Explorer">Internet Explorer</option>
    <option value="Firefox">Firefox</option>
    <option value="Chrome">Chrome</option>
    <option value="Opera">Opera</option>
    <option value="Safari">Safari</option>
</datalist>
```

Thank you

Comment: The entire point of a combobox is that it is a combination of a text input and a drop down menu. If you just want a drop down menu … doesn't your framework offer one?

Comment: Thank you @Quentin

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Quentin mentioned in comments section combobox purpose is to provide a combination of text input and dropdown menu.

You can use `<oj-select-one>` component for your requirement.

```
<oj-select-one id="basicSelect" value="{{val}}" style="max-width:20em">
   <oj-option value="IE">Internet Explorer</oj-option>
   <oj-option value="FF">Firefox</oj-option>
   <oj-option value="CH">Chrome</oj-option>
   <oj-option value="OP">Opera</oj-option>
   <oj-option value="SA">Safari</oj-option>
</oj-select-one>
```

Here is the link for component demo [Oracle Jet SelectOne Menu Demo](http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/jet/jetCookbook.html?component=selectOne&demo=single)

Not sure how it is in jet version you are using but If you wanted to do it with comboxbox only then in jet 5.1 this is working

```
<oj-combobox-one id="student" 
    value="{{selectedStudent}}" options="[[studentOptions]]"
    onkeydown="return false;">
</oj-combobox-one>
```

Comment: If you are using JET by now, with an upper version (>=8.0), you should use <oj-select-single> because the select-one component is now deprecated. [Documentation](https://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/jet/jetCookbook.html?component=selectSingle&demo=states)

Answer (score -1):

Make use of **onkeydown = "return false;"** as one of the attributes in the  component.

```
    `<oj-combobox-one id="combobox" value="{{val}}"
        style="max-width:20em" onkeydown="return false;">
        <oj-option value="Internet Explorer">Internet Explorer</oj-option>
        <oj-option value="Firefox">Firefox</oj-option>
        <oj-option value="Chrome">Chrome</oj-option>
        <oj-option value="Opera">Opera</oj-option>
        <oj-option value="Safari">Safari</oj-option>
     </oj-combobox-one>`
```

You can try it here:
https://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/jet-400/jetCookbook.html?component=comboboxOne&demo=single